# Quote pdf generating error

Tags: pdf, quote

I am creating a quote pdf by code( external user click on any button then code will create this)  and it is successfully created and attached with quote. But the problem is that when I try to view that pdf it shows nothing to me. Then I try to create pdf by "Create pdf" button on Quote record and again pdf created successfully but when try to view internally created pdf it show nothing to me.

So I there are two pdf on quote record. First is created by code (external user) and Second is created by internal user ( by admin by click on create pdf button).

When I click on email link to send these created pdf. I got the email and first pdf is showing nothing and Second pdf showing all data to me which is good to me but I need the first pdf also show me data.

Any solution...

Comment: Please check the access to Quote for the External User! Also Please make sure the Quote Blob that you generate through has any content on it.

Comment: You'd need to post your code for us to give you any kind of diagnosis as to what the real problem is. Your internal button would have different code than the code to create and attach a PDF to an Email. I'm assuming you're doing this as an Admin so would have the proper permissions even if this is for an external user, however the live page may only run from a community or portal so it could be one of not being in the right environment.

Comment: I think we can't get access to external user as customer login profile don't have access on opportunity so quote is a detail of opportunity so we can't give access to community user for quote. If I am wrong than please let me know how can I give access to community user for Quote.